# How do you add a drop down menu with values to a form in microsoft access 2007?

Tags: ms-access

I have a form created in Access 2007, but there is a need to add a dropdown in the form as the answer is usually "YES" or "NO". Any ideas?

Comment: Is it a Bound form or an Unbound form?

Comment: @closers It is a perfectly legal programming question.

Comment: @Raj More - I'm not sure, I'm trying to figure out what the catch is here... "there is a need to add a dropdown in the form" - so add one...?

Comment: sorry, what I mean was how. I see you add a combo box. Once I add it in design view it seems to mess with the layout a bit.

Comment: I don't see how this is a programming question. It's not even one that a power user should have a problem with. It sounds like a question from someone who has not done any tutorials on form design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a combobox and change the row source type to value list
2. Change the row source to "yes";"no"

You can make a multicolumn combobox if you want to associate values with yes/no.

Comment: I knew it would be simple, just needed to know what they called it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just add a combo box.

Comment: Thanks, can you only add that in design view?

Comment: Yes. A combo box is added in design view.
You can set the control source, row source type and row source separately